# Is this a bug or something I am doing wrong?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I cannot imagine how this is anything other than a bug, but since I do not currently have a login for the MS Connect website I will ask here first.

I have Visual Studio 2008 SP 1 with all post SP1 hotfixes I could find relating to the crash installed.  Can you reproduce the following crash?

- Create a new "WPF Application" project using VB as the language (though I suspect it will happen in C# as well).
- Enter the following code in the Window1.xaml.vb file.

> ```
> Friend MustInherit Class A
>
> End Class
>
> Friend MustInherit Class A(Of T)
>     Inherits A
>
> End Class
> ```

- Add a namespace declaration the Window1.xaml file so that it looks like the following.

> ```
> <Window x:Class="Window1"
>     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
>     Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
>     <Grid>
>     </Grid>
> </Window>
> ```

- Now attempt to edit the xaml file by opening a new xml tag via the < character.
- CRASH!

**Edit:** Microsoft has confirmed this bug.  The issue still exists in VS2010 beta 2, but will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: hey mate, i have vs08 vb.net, and i followed your instructions, but could not reproduce the crash. Maybe there is a program you've open in the background that's conflicting with VS? Or does that only happens on Macs... :p

Comment: I know it doesn't help, but I followed your instructions and didn't have any problem.  I'm using VS 2008 Professional, SP1.  Are you able to edit a XAML file in any WPF project?

Comment: Sorry, no repro here either. Have you any 3rd party extensions installed? Have you tried to reset VS?

Comment: This actually sounds like a pre-SP1 bug with the XAML editor. However, since you have that installed, I'm wondering whether it perhaps didn't install correctly/needs a reboot.

Comment: I'm seconding Kent's comment. Got this exact type of problem pre-SP1. Maybe something went wrong updating VS.

Comment: Thanks for responding everyone.  I forgot one crucial step...#3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this by following your instructions, so I'd say a bug exists.

More information on my setup:

- Windows 7 Ultimate
- Visual Studio Team System 2008 (Version 9.0.30729.1 SP)

I wasn't able to reproduce this using C#, only VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  This was a particularly difficult bug to figure out.  It took me about 4 hours to troubleshoot it and find the minimal steps necessary to reproduce.  I never thought having two classes with the same name would be the culprit.  I also could not reproduce this with C#.

Comment: If you want to make this example as concise as possible, you can also leave out `Friend MustInherit` from your class definitions.